# Creating gist failed: 403 Forbidden

Tags: macos, git, github, gist

This is the error message I am receiving when trying to create a new gist.

> Creating gist failed: 403 Forbidden

I have set up GITHUB_USER and GITHUB_PASSWORD as suggested and have tried setting up the environment variable HTTP_PROXY but then I receive this error:

> System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/1.8/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/uri/generic.rb:195:in `initialize': the scheme http does not accept registry part: host:port (or bad hostname?) (URI::InvalidURIError)
>       from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/1.8/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/uri/http.rb:78:in`initialize'
>       from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/1.8/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/uri/common.rb:488:in `new'
>       from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/1.8/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/uri/common.rb:488:in`parse'
>       from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/1.8/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/uri/common.rb:608:in `URI'
>       from /usr/local/bin/gist:1130

Can't seem to find any support to do with either error!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There might be many reasons to get 403 response from Github, in both existed tools or your own code, for example:

- User-Agent is not set in the API requests (http://developer.github.com/changes/2013-04-24-user-agent-required)
- You (code or tool) exceed API requests limits (not sure it's your case however as usually limits are high enough)